# Drawing a user-defined tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, drawing, metalanguage

I am making a pretty abstract tree drawing system, but I am having quite a lot of trouble formalizing all the drawing features it should have. I'd very much appreciate if someone could point me to things to read about this topic, because unfortunately my searches have been in vain.

I am looking for/trying to make a meta-language for displaying trees. In these trees each node is an instance of a user-defined Object which have a user-defined graphical representation.

Each Object is associated with a Name, a graphical representation and has a finite number of childs ( 0+ ), which are only known to be Objects themselves. Object recursion is not allowed.
Each Object may have user-defined Options that are used to trigger conditions which would change their graphical representation ( in user-defined ways ). Some Options are automatically applied, others may require user interaction ( "Would you like this Object to be A or B?" ), thus explaining why Object trees need to be instanced.

```
Object
    Name                // The Object Name
    Childs              // List of Object Childs
        ContextName         // The Name of the Child within this context
        Types               // List of Objects' names. This child may be only one of them. Decided by the user during instancing.
        Options             // List of Options assigned to this child. Some of them may require user interaction, and apply other Options to the Child's childs.
        *Priority           // This is an integer which is used to decide the order in which childs are drawn.
    Symbol Name         // The Graphical representation of the Object
```

Once an Object Tree has been instanced, it has to be drawn without any addictional user input, and this is where I am having some trouble. The instancing of an Object tree assigns to each Object a particular graphical representation ( let's call it Symbol ). The assignment is however not known before the instancing. Different Objects may also have the same Symbol, which may be drawn differently depending on the Object's Options.

Because of this, Symbols must be defined separately from Objects, and must have a series of abstract mechanisms to be able to draw themselves ( and thir assigned childs ) correctly, following the user-specified rules.

Each Symbol is represented by an image ( or no image ) plus a finite number of Attachments. Attachments are relative positions to the Symbol's coordinates which tell the drawing code where to draw the Symbols of the Object's childs. Each one of them may have particular conditions to be used ( e.g. this Attachment may only be used by a Symbol that has a particular Option, or if N Symbols have already been drawn, no collisions with already drawn Symbols etc etc ).

The algorithm has to find a free Attachment for each Object's child, following the order specified by their Priority. If it is not possible to find an Attachment for a Child the user may specify beforehand rules that allow some automatic retries, but if they also fail then the whole tree drawing fails. Some of these rules allow for adding addictional child Symbols and/or assigning child Symbols to other childs ( making them grandChildren ) etc.

```
Symbol
    Name
    Main Image      // Image Path, Height, Width
    Attachments     // List of the attachments, their position, requirements and addictional infos
    Fail Rules      // List of actions to do if it is not possible to successfully assign each Child to an Attachment
```

My main problem is that the number of variables that a Symbol should be able to access is pretty high. Each Symbol, which I'll again remind should be defined using this meta-language, should be able to access its child Symbols' informations ( not others to avoid deadlocks and circular referencing ): for example the user may want the heigth and width of a Symbol to be equal to the sum of the heigth and width of all the Child's Symbols, or to use the same picture, and so on. This is also caused by the fact that the user writes Symbols' rules independently from the final structure.

At the same time, since the tree must be drawn from top to bottom, some of these informations may not be available from the start, and may require a great deal of backtracking.

Also, since all of this has to be defined within a meta-language which I have to be able formalize and parse, I have to define which are the functions that the meta-language requires to allow the maximum grade of freedom to the language-writing user without being overly complex ( this is a vague limit, but essentially I don't want to have Tikz as a subset of my meta-language ). I am having however quite a bit of trouble identifying them.

As I said before, I am looking for informations about this kind of topic and/or methods for completing a project like this. Once I'll be able to fully complete the meta-language I think I won't have too much trouble implementing the code to do all of this, my problems are for the most part theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a few similar projects with hierarchical data.  I point you to where I started:

Joe Celko is the king of tree data.  I recommend you start with his book.  It is a mix of logic and business case.  Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties even has a new edition out.  There is a language for describing the hierarchies there, too.

I have used Oracle for storing my hierarchies which has a very efficient system for pulling and storing tree data.  Look up "connect by" either in documentation or in the book:  Mastering Oracle SQL by Mishra and Beaulieu.

You can use pointers to pull the images from the server so you wouldn't store them in the database.  I have built several systems that use hierarchical displays of data with graphical objects, it keeps the overhead down this way.  DevExpress and Telerik both have great viewers for displaying the trees and I have mine build the next levels dynamically.  It doesn't know how many or what the next level is going to be until it is drilled down on.  Try these examples and read the docs and you will be able to put this together in not time.

For telerik this link will show you multiple load on demand views:  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/programming/loadondemandmodes/defaultcs.aspx

For Devexpress:  http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxTreeListDemos/Data/VirtualMode.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is most related to describing the shape and visual representation of the tree ( by defining each Symbol shape and Attachments and connecting them in a structure using Object trees ), not so much on the data.

Comment: Celko's books cover that, its part of the way it all is referenced. You are referring to the metadata that is used for describing the trees.  Representing objects is not unusual.  Numbers, objects, clusters of words, files, images, etc are all described using the same system.  Even when using data from a database you would use the same terms.   Their is already language to describe it.  It comes partially from the math world.  You can try looking for XML based references if the SQL is unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

Think in HTML/DOM.

I was surprised, when I found, that the file format of the **outliner** I am using, NoteCase, is plain HTML. NoteCase can be found here: http://notecase.sourceforge.net/index1.html

*If you don't familiar with it, *outliner* is an application type, which you can organize mainly text nodes in hierarchical tree. There are task outliners, too. When an outliner has graphical representation, it's called **mind mapping**. Anyway, the directory structure of a filesystem is an outline, too. There are lot of outliners for various areas. See Wikipedia for more details.*

Notecase uses DL/DT/DD: DL is the list, DT is the item, and DD is the description of an item. They can be nested, of course.

1. If the format is HTML, you need only a CSS to show it in a browser easy readable for human eyes.
2. If you have additional properties, you can define additional tags or attributes, which browser will not show, but your renderer can.
3. You should write a converter, which transforms your source HTML file format to a more detailed HTML format, which contains *computed* fields (e.g. which sums of values from the sub-nodes, or replaces "inherit" marks in a sub-node with the inherited value from parent node), some additional formatting, or you can transform attributes into HTML nodes:

   `<node type="x" size="y" />`

   to

   `<div class="node">` 
       `<div class="param"> type: x </div>` 
       `<div class="param"> size: y </div>` 
   `</div>`
4. Your data representation is a kinda DOM, and you should process it similar way. First, parse and read values from the file. Then, you should run some additional rounds (walk the tree) to fill missing values with defaults, calculate inherited and summarized values etc.

   I think, you can't use standard DOM parsers, because you mentioned custom *sorting* of stuff depending on parameters, which DOM modell doesn't really support.
5. Don't afraid to walk the object tree just as many **passes** as many operation you want to perform on it. You can play with changing the order of the passes, enabling and disabling passes... as your have more and more features, it will articulated as new processing passes.

   You may have passes, which must be run several times, e.g. if one pass can't calculate a value (because it's source should be calculated first), it may return a flag that "I've not done yet", and it should run again on the tree, until it results "no change mades, I've done".

I hope I've push you a bit.

Comment: The base of my meta-language is JSON, and yes, what I am trying to make is pretty much a language to describe a mind-map.
However mind-mapping software works by adding individual nodes to a predefined structure, while I have to describe beforehand the visuals/reactions of each node ( Symbol ) so that they are able, after being placed in a tree-like hierarchy, to coordinate autonomously to build a complex and orderly structure, as imagined by the user. Note that the final structure may not look like a tree. I've not seen any software that describes unique node-types and then links them.@ern0